# jQuery не видит данные формы

Tags: html, jquery, webix

Использую webix UI, код JS:

```js
this.add = function () {
  scrollArea.css("overflow", "hidden");
  $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "/detail/create",
   success: function (form) {
    webix.message.keyboard = false;
    webix.modalbox({
     title: "Новая деталь",
     buttons: ["ДОБАВИТЬ", "ОТМЕНА"],
     text: form,
     width: 400,
     callback: function (result) {
      switch (result) {
       case "0":
        addDetail();
        break;
       case "1":
        break;
      }
      scrollArea.css("overflow", "auto");
     }
    });
   }
  });
  function addDetail() {
   $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
     'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
   });
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/detail/store",
    data: $('#detail_add').serialize(),
    contentType: "JSON",
    processData: false,
    success: function () {
    }
   });
  }
 };
```

```html
<form action="" id="detail_add" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Название">
 <input type="text" name="article" placeholder="Артикул">
 <input type="hidden" name="location_id" placeholder="1">
 <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
</form>
```

При нажатии на кнопку ПРИМЕНИТЬ, отправляется пустой JSON.
В чем может быть дело?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ - нужно было использовать

```
switch (result) {
    case "0":
      addDetail;
    break;
    case "1":
    break;
}
```

Вместо

```
switch (result) {
    case "0":
      addDetail();
    break;
    case "1":
    break;
}
```

Т.к. таким образом функция вызывалась еще при вызове модального окна.